Hibernate integrator - Unknown service org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry
Hibernate 6.6.1.Final, Spring boot 3.3.4
I try to add event listeners to my project but I'm getting this exception when I start the application:
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry] 
at fr.sofia.sad.service.config.EventListenerIntegrator.integrate(EventListenerIntegrator.java:16)

Here is my configuration:
public class EventListenerIntegrator implements Integrator {

    @Override
    public void integrate(Metadata metadata, BootstrapContext bootstrapContext, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {
        final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = bootstrapContext.getServiceRegistry()
                                                                            .getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT, PostInsertUpdateEventListener.class);
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE, PostInsertUpdateEventListener.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(final SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, final SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        //empty
    }
}

If I reference my integrator directly spring is telling me that there is a cast exception because my integrator is not a org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider so that's how I register it in my application.yml:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integrator_provider: config.HibernateIntegratorProvider
With
import org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator;
import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider;

public class HibernateIntegratorProvider implements IntegratorProvider {

    @Override
    public List<Integrator> getIntegrators() {
        return List.of(new EventListenerIntegrator());
    }
}

I dont understand why the service is unknown and that's the way hibernate documentation recommend for creating the integrator:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-event-listener-registration

If you want to add an event listener to your application, you must implement its interface. In Hibernate, each event has its own interface, there are quite a few of them, you can find these interfaces in the org.hibernate.event.spi package. Let's say you need to track the loading of objects, then you need the LoadEventListener interface:
public class CustomEventListener implements LoadEventListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomEventListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType) throws HibernateException {
        LOGGER.info("load event");
    }
}


In order for your listener to be able to respond to events, he must be registered in the listener registry:
@Configuration
public class HibernateListenerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerHibernateEventListeners() {
        SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class );
        sessionFactory
                .getServiceRegistry()
                .getService( EventListenerRegistry.class )
                .prependListeners(EventType.LOAD, new CustomEventListener());
    }
}

For more information, see сhapter 15.2 of the Hibernate ORM User Guide.

Thanks for replying, but the main point of my question was to register my event listener with an integrator like in the link of the documentation I shared. If it's not possible then I guess I will use the @PostConstruct way.

@gb2 Chapter 4.1 describes the native bootstrapping process, where you must manage the bootstrapping process yourself. If you are using Spring Boot, the framework manages the bootstrapping process, and you must act as described in Chapter 15.2.

Quite enlightening! In my case, springboot is indeed bootstrapping the EntityManagerFactory. But then I find the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integrator_provider attribute misleading, like you re using springboot configuration without bootstrapping? Anyway I had no difficulty switching to the @PostConstruct eventlistener registering.
